# Always apply personal patch during checkout

Tags: git

I am working on a big project using Git.

- I have a problem running the code and I have a patch to fix it.
- The problem is that this patch cannot be integrated into the official branches since it is relative a problem affecting only me.

So every time I do a checkout of a remote branch I need to apply my personal patch.

- When pushing my changes I also need to remember to don't push my patch.

Is there a way to simplify my workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in these cases is keep that change in a private branch, just that change. Let's call it `X/fix`.... so, when I want to start working I do:

```
git show X/fix | git apply -
```

Now, when I want to get it out of the way (like, I need to add changes to index and I don't want to see them there.... and I know I can use `git add -i` but **still**), I do:

```
git show X/fix | git apply -R -
```

And then the changes are gone.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `post-checkout` hook that is called after a successful `git checkout` and a `pre-commit` hook that is (you saw it coming, didn't you ^^) executed before the commit takes place. See [this doc](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks) for some good info and examples.

With those hooks you should be able to apply and "un-apply" your patch.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention what your patch looks like. If it is a specific file that you copy into the project, you could add it to the [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file and that could be checked in to the project, as no one else would have your patch file.

For the checkout process, maybe you could write a shell script in the shell of your chosing to copy the files into the directory. You could name it checkout.sh or something and start with a git checkout command. You could even have the branch name as a parameter and the main branch as default.

Such a script could also be used to autmomatically change code on checkout if your patch is of that nature (be careful with this automation though). In that case, checking in without your patch seems not doable, sadly.

Comment: You can have your own personal ignore list at `.git/info/exclude`.